# Editable Combobox doesnt keep its value

Tags: combobox, javafx, javafx-8

I have a problem using an editable combobox.
When I choose a value from the drop down menu it has to be shown within the combobox and has to be written into an extra textfield, it works as long as the combobox is focused.

The Problem here is, that when I set focus on another element by pressing enter or tab as well as when I click on another element, the values in the textfield and in the combobox just disappear.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I guess it should'nt happen if you use the bidirectionnal binding feature provided by JavaFX between the combobox and your textfield properties.

Comment: @Kwoinkwoin can you explain this more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

I post an answer to detail my comment (asked by Zydar)

With JavaFX, you can bind some properties each other in order to sync their value. Here is a perfect case to use this. It should be bone like this :

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFxTest extends Application {


    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("value1", "value2", "value3"));
        cb.setEditable(true);

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.textProperty().bind(cb.getEditor().textProperty());
        // Use the following if you want the bind to be bidirectional
        // tf.textProperty().bindBidirectional(cb.getEditor().textProperty());

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane(cb, tf);
        Scene scene = new Scene(flowPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JavaFxTest.launch(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: Binding a TextField and a ComboBox doesn't keep the text in the editable ComboBox from disappearing once it loses focus !